# Which preposition should I use after "well versed"?

Tags: prepositions

If I say " I am well versed in mathematics" and if I say " I am well versed with mathematics" so, which of the above is correct and why?
Can I say I am well versed in the knowledge or with the knowledge? How to use this well versed in a sentence?? Help needed...

Answer (score 4):

You are using well versed to talk about a skill, therefore you should use "in." Now you will get the sentence:

> I am well versed in mathematics.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to say with this sentence, "I am well versed in the knowledge." But this is also correct, grammatically. It just doesn't really mean anything without some context about said knowledge.

Comment: I can say this"I am well versed in the knowledge of mathematics" or not??

Comment: There's no need to use "in the knowledge of" in this case. You should only use "in the knowledge of" when you are talking about something and it's not clear that it is a skill. An example I found of this was about knowledge of horses: "I am well versed in the knowledge of horses"

Answer (score 2):

***[Well versed](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well-versed)*** means:

> - knowing a lot about something:
>
>   - *He was well versed ***in*** modern history.*

As highlighted by the Cambridge Dictionary the idiomatic preposition that is used with well-versed is ***"in"***.

Also according  to the evidence offered by  [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=well%20versed%20in%2Cwell%20versed%20at%2Cwell%20versed%20on%2Cwell%20versed%20about%2Cwell%20versed%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwell%20versed%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20versed%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20versed%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20versed%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20versed%20with%3B%2Cc0) "well versed" is generally followed by "in". Other prepositions can be found but they are much less commonly used.

For instance:

From [Science, Race and Religion...](https://books.google.it/books?id=4IULBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA122&dq=%22well%20versed%20on%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic246Zj63PAhUaOsAKHUFHBkYQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22well%20versed%20on%22&f=false):

> - Thus, although he devoted considerable time to botany and was extremely ***well versed on the subject***, he made comparatively few original contributions to the field.

- The expression "well versed" refers to the "knowledge in something" so it is redundant to say "I am well versed in the knowledge of..."